# Small glitch with EdgeForm and PlotRange

Tags: plotting, graphics, output

I'm experiencing a small problem with the edges of a square, if the PlotRange has the same size as the square :

```
aSquare = Graphics[{
    EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Black]], GrayLevel[0.5], Opacity[0.1],
    Polygon[{{0, -Pi/2}, {Pi, -Pi/2}, {Pi, Pi/2}, {0, Pi/2}}]
}];

Show[
    {aSquare},
    PlotRange -> {{0, Pi}, {-Pi/2, Pi/2}},
    PlotRangeClipping -> True,
    Frame -> None,
    Axes -> True,
    AxesOrigin -> {Pi/2, 0},
    AxesStyle -> GrayLevel[0.75]
]
```

This code will show the square with two sides having their thickness cut-off in part.  All four sides should have exactly the same thickness.

I can solve the issue if I use `PlotRange -> {{0 - 0.01, Pi + 0.01}, {-Pi/2 - 0.01, Pi/2 + 0.01}}` instead, but this feels like an "hack", and don't seems to be very natural.

What should be the best way of showing that square with its thick borders, while still using the same size for `PlotRange` ?  Take note that I need to keep `PlotRangeClipping -> True` to cut off some curves that goes outside the square.

Comment: Use `PlotRange -> All` in `Show`?

Comment: I'm not sure this will work, once I add all the curves.  Those curves need to be shown inside the square only (thus the `PlotRangeClipping -> True` option).

Comment: Perhaps add a very small amount of padding to the plot range (e.g. `PlotRangePadding -> 0.01`)? Depending on how your curves are defined, which you don't specify, you might be able to use a `RegionFunction` to have them plotted only within the square.

Answer (score 2):

I think it may be more expedient to use `Framed` to generate the frame you want, rather than having an extra graphics object:

```
Framed[
  Show[
    {
      Graphics[{Red, Thick, Circle[]}],
      Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2, 5}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Blue]]
    },
    PlotRange -> {{0, Pi}, {-Pi/2, Pi/2}},
    (*REMOVED*)
    (*PlotRangeClipping -> True,*)
    (**)
    Frame -> None, Axes -> True,
    AxesOrigin -> {Pi/2, 0}, AxesStyle -> GrayLevel[0.75],
    (*ADDED*)
    ImagePadding -> None
    (**)
  ],
  FrameMargins -> 0,
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
  Background -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.5], Opacity[0.1]]
]
```

[image: graphics results]

Comment: I don't know why, but I don't get a thick frame.  Removing `Thick`doesn't make any difference. (what the ...?)

Comment: @Cham Could you try replacing `Thick` with an appropriate `AbsoluteThickness` directive? I tried `AbsoluteThickness[3]` in the `FrameStyle` and it looks OK, but you might want to try something outrageous, e.g. 10 or so, to see if it is even doing anything. I'm on 10.4.0; you are on a somewhat older version of MMA if I remember correctly, is that right?

Comment: @Cham Also, does the `Circle` show up as a thick line? That's also using `Thick`, so I wonder why it would work somewhere but not everywhere!

Comment: The Thickness doesn't change anything.  The curves are all okay though.  Yep, I'm on a prehistoric and archaic MMA 7.  I'm currently playing with the Frame options.  It appears to do the job for the moment.